# fgets in C doesn't return a portion of an string

Tags: c, string, search, position

I'm totally new in C, and I'm trying to do a little application that searches for a string in a file. My problem is that I need to open a big file (more than 1GB) with just one line inside and fgets return me the entire file (I'm doing test with a 10KB file).

Actually this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 char *search = argv[argc-1];

 int retro = strlen(search);
 int pun  = 0;
 int sortida;
 int limit = 10;

 char ara[20];

 FILE *fp; 
 if ((fp = fopen ("SEARCHFILE", "r")) == NULL){
  sortida = -1;
  exit (1);
 }

 while(!feof(fp)){
  if (fgets(ara, 20, fp) == NULL){
   break;
  }
  //this must be a 20 bytes line, but it gets the entyre 10Kb file
  printf("%s",ara);
 }

    sortida = 1;

 if(fclose(fp) != 0){
  sortida = -2;
  exit (1);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

What can I do to find an string into a file?

I've tried with GREP but it don't helps, because it returns the position:ENTIRE_STRING.

I'm open to ideas.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your comment, _this must be a 20 bytes line, but it gets the entire 10KB file_? Do you mean that the entire 10KB are printed on one line? (How could you tell the difference whether the whole 10KB are output in one go or whether 20B chunks are output one at a time, if you don't include some separator character after every print operation? It's impossible to tell the difference. jim mcnamara's answer would seem reasonable.)

Comment: feof + fgets is not good. see http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html.

Comment: @stakx, that's for the \n miss. At moment it's OK :). Thanks for your atention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
printf("%s\n",ara);
```

Also consider initializing variables before you use them:

```
char ara[20]={0x0};
```

Comment: I have no idea how `printf` would solve his problem, and there's no need to initialize `ara` here, as `fgets` is going to overwrite it

Comment: %s\n  makes the string print as a new line each time \n == newline character

Comment: Oh, I see, you were saying to add the `\n` to the end of his existing printf. Got it

Comment: @michael - Best Practice == initialize all strings to nuls. Always.

Comment: hopely OP understood that the reason why it "looked" as if it has read "the whole file" is that printing even one read byte after another results in the original file as output, not surprising; and that searching string this way is not so easy since the string could be "split" into two separated 20byte block, and the separation avoid recognization of the string

Comment: @jim Nonsense; it's good practice if you're learning and/or you don't trust yourself not to screw it up, but there's no reason to initialize a variable that's going to be overwritten immediately after the declaration

Comment: There's no need to do initialization.

Comment: Nyan - Michael.  Consider reading 'Code complete', 2nd Ed, Chap 10. p 241.  If I understand you, you mean "don't init variables" if you think/hope/suspect some operation nearby is going to clean it out for you. Correct?  Obviously I disagree.

Answer (score 1):

You only allocated 20 bytes for the input buffer, but told the fgets to read 20 bytes.

Make this change:

```
  if (fgets(ara, sizeof(ara)-1, fp) == NULL){
```

remember, if you want 20 characters PLUS the trailing '\0' that marks the end of the string you  have to allocate 21 bytes.